# Unity only rendering certian parts of 3d building model from certian angles

Tags: unity, rendering, 3d-meshes

So I made a couple modular building sections in blender, modular in the sense that I can insert build a floor at a time. I transferred them into Unity and then I got a rendering error that  I have gotten many times before. I will put the object in the game world and then certain chunks of the building will only be visible from on direction and the other it will be completely invisible. I have been having trouble with this bug for a long time and I really would like if someone could point out what's causing this problem. I will include pictures below to help show my problem.

Thanks, Nova

[image: Outside of building]

[image: Inside of building]

Comment: Can you turn face culling off? It looks like maybe your face normals are messed up and if you turn culling off for your render it might fix the graphical glitches.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to.

Comment: The second image appears to have been taken from inside the building. If so, all of the triangles are reversed and you are only seeing the faces that should be culled. Clock-wise, viewed from behind, is counter. Anytime you are inside of a mesh, you most-likely need to reverse the culling.

Comment: Blender 2.73, 'N' is the properties panel and, with an object in edit mode, under "Mesh Display", there are "checkboxes" to visualize the normals. As a quick check, turn on faces and drag the slider until they are obvious.

Comment: "Backface Culling" is also on the properties panel, under "Shading", outside of edit mode. Activating it should produce an image similar to the one Unity creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second image appears to have been taken from inside the building. If so, all of the triangles are reversed and you are only seeing the faces that should be culled. Likewise, faces that should be visible are being culled.

Ordinarily, meshes are drawn from the outside-inward so, when you are inside, looking outward, the triangles that were clock-wise from the outside, now appear counter-clockwise and are culled.

Anytime you are inside of a mesh, you most-likely need to reverse the culling.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CullMode.html